# Error when calling insertionsort method and how to print an arraylist

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, insertion-sort

I have created a program which stores temperature(double) and day(string) in an arraylist, then uses the comparable interface and an insertion sort to sort the arraylist. Now all that i have left is calling the insertion sort method and print out the original order of the arraylist and the sorted order. However when I call the insertionsort method it gives me an error stating "invalid method declaration; return type required".  Why am i receiving this error? Also is my print statement correct to print out the original arraylist? How would i update it to print out the sorted arraylist? Or can i print that out from the insertionsort method?

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DailyTemperature implements Comparable<DailyTemperature>
{
     //variables
    private Double temperature;
    private String day;

    //getTemp & setTemp methods
    public double getTemp()
    {
      return temperature;
    }

    public void setTemp(double newTemp)
    {
      temperature = newTemp;
    }

    //getDay & setTEmp methods
    public String getDay()
    {
      return day;
    }

    public void setDay(String newDay)
    {
      day = newDay;
    }


    public DailyTemperature(String day, double temperature) 
    {
      this.day = day;
      this.temperature = temperature;
    }

    public int compareTo(DailyTemperature other) 
    {
        if (temperature < other.temperature) return -1;
        if (temperature == other.temperature) return 0;
        return 1;
    }

    public String toString() 
    {
        return("Day of Week" + this.getDay() +
        "Temperature" + this.getTemp());
    }


}



import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DailyTemperatureList 
{
    public static void main (String [] args) 
    {

    ArrayList<DailyTemperature> dailytemps = new ArrayList<DailyTemperature>();

    dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Mon", 87.1));
    dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Tue", 88.3));
    dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Wed", 81.2));
    dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Thu", 84.0));
    dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Fri", 76.3));
   }

   public static <DailyTemperature extends Comparable<? super DailyTemperature>>
   void insertionSort(ArrayList<DailyTemperature> dailytemps)
   {
       DailyTemperature temp = null;
       int position = 0;

       //loop from 2nd element on
       for (int i = 1; i < dailytemps.size(); i++)
       {
           temp = dailytemps.get(i);
           position = i;

           while ( 0 < position && temp.compareTo(dailytemps.get(position - 1 )) < 0)
           {
               dailytemps.set(position, dailytemps.get(position - 1));
               position--;
           }
            dailytemps.set(position,temp);
        }
    }

    insertionSort(ArrayList<DailyTemperature> dailytemps);
    System.out.println( dailytemps.toString() );





}
```

Comment: @WilliamGaul. Huh! That's not return type, that's type parameter declaration. Return type of method is `void` only.

Comment: First of all, while invoking a method, you don't give the type of the argument you pass. It is automatically inferred from formal parameter type. Secondly, you have to invoke the method from inside a method, say `main`. Currently you are invoking it from outside all the methods. You can't have statements directly inside a  class.

Comment: @RohitJain Whoops...did not see the `void` on the next line. I was wondering why the "return type" was formatted so weirdly :P

Comment: OK, I think you want to add the call to `insertionSort` and the line below it up into the main method.  Remove the `ArrayList<DailyTemperature>` from that line too.  And remove the part inside <> (the part after `static` but before `void`) from the signature of `insertSort`.  That ought to do it.

Comment: @DavidWallace I fixed it, but it does not print out the sorted array it prints out a random order: this is the output"[Day of Week: Fri Temperature: 76.3, Day of Week: Thu Temperature: 84.0, Day of Week: Wed Temperature: 81.2, Day of Week: Tue Temperature: 88.3, Day of Week: Mon Temperature: 87.1]"

Comment: OK.  That doesn't look random to me.  That looks like just the reverse order of how the list started.  So there's something wrong with your sort.  Why are you doing a loop there?  Can't you just use `Collections.sort(dailytemps)` instead of trying to implement your own sorting algorithm?

Comment: Now that I look at your code more closely, I think you can probably get rid of the `insertionSort` method entirely, and just write `Collections.sort(dailytemps);` instead of the call to `insertionSort`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However when I call the insertionsort method it gives me an error stating "invalid method declaration; return type required". Why am i receiving this error?

You are calling insertionSort() inside DailyTemperatureList class but outside any method which does not compile.
I moved the call into  main() method, so that it compiles, see bellow.

> Also is my print statement correct to print out the original arraylist? How would i update it to print out the sorted arraylist? Or can i print that out from the insertionsort method?

Print out the original list before calling insertionSort(), and after sorting it print out the sorted list:

```
System.out.println( "original list:" );
System.out.println( dailytemps.toString() );

insertionSort( dailytemps);
System.out.println( "sorted list:" );
```

Output:

```
original list: [Day of WeekMonTemperature87.1, Day of WeekTueTemperature88.3, Day of WeekWedTemperature81.2, Day of WeekThuTemperature84.0, Day of WeekFriTemperature76.3] 

sorted list: [Day of WeekFriTemperature76.3, Day of WeekWedTemperature81.2, Day of WeekThuTemperature84.0, Day of WeekMonTemperature87.1, Day of WeekTueTemperature88.3]
```

Corrected DailyTemperatureList class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DailyTemperatureList
{
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {

    ArrayList<DailyTemperature> dailytemps = new ArrayList<DailyTemperature>();

    dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Mon", 87.1));
    dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Tue", 88.3));
    dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Wed", 81.2));
    dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Thu", 84.0));
    dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Fri", 76.3));

    System.out.println( "original list:" );
    System.out.println( dailytemps.toString() );

    insertionSort( dailytemps);
    System.out.println( "sorted list:" );
    System.out.println( dailytemps.toString() );



  }

  //public static <DailyTemperature extends Comparable<? super DailyTemperature>>
  static void insertionSort(ArrayList<DailyTemperature> dailytemps)
  {
    DailyTemperature temp = null;
    int position = 0;

    //loop from 2nd element on
    for (int i = 1; i < dailytemps.size(); i++)
    {
      temp = dailytemps.get(i);
      position = i;

      while ( 0 < position && temp.compareTo(dailytemps.get(position - 1 )) < 0)
      {
        dailytemps.set(position, dailytemps.get(position - 1));
        position--;
      }
      dailytemps.set(position,temp);
    }
  }






}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! Can I ask how it worked for you? Because when I called moved the call method and the print statement to the main method i was getting this order: [Day of Week: Fri Temperature: 76.3, Day of Week: Thu Temperature: 84.0, Day of Week: Wed Temperature: 81.2, Day of Week: Tue Temperature: 88.3, Day of Week: Mon Temperature: 87.1]" - which isn't the original order or the sorted order

Comment: Hmm, don't know, you should've gotten a sorted list. It seems you've printed the original list, but in reversed order. Are you sure you did't change anything else, like the sorting algorithm for example. Or the compareTo() method?

Comment: I'm not sure if this matters but I took the the implements Comparable<DailyTemperature> from the DailyTemperature class and it worked. but when I added it back in I received the output I was getting before. now I took it out and I am still receiving the same wrong output.

Comment: what does this line do: Collections.sort(dailytemps);? this line errors out.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it does nothing, I was just testing it and forgot to remove it. I'll edit the post and remove it.